# How to animate the css zoom property

Tags: javascript, css, zooming

Is it possible to get a smooth transition for the css zoom property?

I googled a lot, but the results for the keywords "css" and "zoom" are always about transform and transition. So, I don't want to know how to do it with transform and scale and so on. Just with the css zoom property.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('zoom');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.zoom {
  zoom: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div>click me!</div>
```

Comment: well if you want to animate it with pure css you would need to add a `transition` to define the property to animate, the duration and the easing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function zoomIn(tg) {
    let fr = 100;
    setInterval(function() {
        if(fr < 200) {
            fr++;
            tg.style.zoom = fr + "%";
        };
    }, 5);
}

function zoomOut(tg) {
    let fr = 200;
    setInterval(function() {
        if(fr > 100) {
            fr--;
            tg.style.zoom = fr + "%";
        };
    }, 5);
}


document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('zoom')) {
      e.target.classList.remove("zoom")
      zoomOut(e.target);
  } else {
      e.target.classList.add("zoom");
      zoomIn(e.target);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div>click me!</div>
```

Comment: sorry i was just testing forgot to remove it

Answer (score 2):

> Non-standard This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.
>
> The non-standard zoom CSS property can be used to control the
>   magnification level of an element. transform: scale() should be used
>   instead of this property, if possible. However, unlike CSS Transforms,
>   zoom affects the layout size of the element.
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom)

So, you can use `scale` for this.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('zoom');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition:.5s;
  transform-origin:left top;
}

.zoom {
  transform:scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div>click me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [css transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp), for your case:

```
.zoom {
    transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}
```

Here all times that this width and height div changes will get 1 second